# Customize woocommerce user authentication

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to make a third party API call using the posted `username` and `password` just before the user authorization in `woocommerce`.But I could'nt figure out the function handling the authorization.

This is the shortcode for user login

```
[woocommerce_my_account]
```

I just want to do

```
if api call success
       -->authentication
else 
       -->some other action
```

Do somebody know the function/file handling this post data or user authentication?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to authenticate existing customer via WooCommerce rest API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46022349/how-to-authenticate-existing-customer-via-woocommerce-rest-api)

Answer (score 1):

There no different login function for woocommerce. it use default wp_login() function.
Please check 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login

Hope it will work.